# SQL CASE [Column] WHEN IN ('case1', 'case2') THEN 'oops' END?

Tags: sql-server, syntax, case, sql

Is there a way to check a CASE when it's in an array:

```
SELECT CASE [Option] WHEN IN (1, 3, 99) THEN 'Wrong option' ELSE 'You go!' END
```

Comment: I wanna check if Option equal to one of the items in (1, 3, 99) should return 'Wrong option', else - 'You go!'.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Option] IN (1, 3, 99) THEN 'Wrong option' ELSE 'You go' END
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `CASE WHEN <predicate> THEN <value> ... END` option, rather than the `CASE <value> WHEN <value> THEN <value> ... END` option.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Option] IN (1, 3, 99) THEN 'Wrong option' ELSE 'You go!' END
```

... but if the values are in a table, you could just do an outer join (and

```
CASE WHEN t.Value IS NULL THEN 'Not in list' ELSE 'In list' END
```

, or

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable t WHERE t.value = [Option]) THEN 'Bad' ELSE 'Ok' END
```

...without a join.